# addClass/removeClass with navigation pills jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been working on this one tiny problem for a few hours now, and could really use some help. I have three Bootstrap navigation pills:

[image]

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li class="home-class"><a href="#home-page" id="home">Home</a></li>     
            <li class="resume-class"><a href="#resume-page" id="resume">Resume</a></li>         
            <li class="contact-class"><a href="#contact-page" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

When I scroll to a certain area of the webpage, it'll automatically highlight that navigation pill to a white font (this is taken care of in jQuery).

What SHOULD happen is that when I scroll to, let's say, the Resume section, all the other pills should not be highlighted. However, when I click on Resume, and then scroll to Contact/Home, Resume remains highlighted - looks like this:

[image]

CSS:

```
.nav-pills > li > a {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #a9a9a9;
}

.nav-pills > li.active > a {
    background-color: #536872;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

jQuery (this is very unoptimized, sorry):

```
var home = $('#section1').offset();
var resume = $('#section2').offset();
var contact = $('#section3').offset()

//Change active class when scrolling
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var position = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (position <= home.top - 80) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (position >= home.top - 80) {
        $('.home-class').addClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (position > resume.top - 50) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').addClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (position > contact.top - 50) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

TL;DR -- scrolling to certain aspects of webpage highlights that respective section on the navigation pill, but when I start to click on the pill and then scroll, more than one navigation pill is highlighted. My question is - why doesn't `removeClass('active')` get rid of the `.active` class when I click + scroll?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle or Codepen? Before that, my first guess is to look at your `.active` how it is being set, how it is being removed, how it is **not** being removed. Perhaps when you click on it, the `.active` is being set, but when you use scroll, you are not *unsetting* the existing `.active` element properly.

Comment: If it isn't active, doesn't `.nav-pills > li > a` take care of that? So when a pill's active class is removed, it should return to the behavior set by `.nav-pills > li > a`? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't see what is the problem https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/447/

Comment: Just kidding. For some reason, it's working on jsfiddle but isn't working on my local file...

Comment: I suggest you set a breakpoint in the code and then single-step through it when you click on the pill.

Answer (score 0):

Are you forced to use jQuery? Bootstrap provides a fully automated feature for that, called `scrollspy`. If you can use Bootstrap take a look into this:
https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Also, here is a very clear example of how to use it.
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

Comment: He's already using bootstrap, so I guess it's safe to assume he can use it.

Comment: Well, sorry then didn't notice that. But in that case, why use some jQuery when there is a Bootstrap functinallity providing exactly what you are lookin for?

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, I'll definitely give that a try. It's just that I'm mainly using this project to familiarize myself with jQuery. I'm also very close to figuring this out (the above jsfiddle works with my code exactly, but doesn't work on my local file which is very perplexing.)